# Common script for all jobs inheriting a hidden one in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

We have a common included CI config file (`.services.yml`) for a set of projects looking like this:

```yaml
stages:
 - ...
 - build
 - ...

.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - build_script
    - ...
  ...
```

The `.build` job is used in each project a few times in order to build different binaries for a set of stage platforms:

```yaml
include:
  - project: "project/path"
    ref: master
    file: /.services.yml

build-stage1:
  extends: .build
  ...

build-stage2:
  extends: .build
  ...
```

However some projects using the `.services.yml` don't inherit the `.build` job as it's unnecessary.

We have decided to make an 'extra build' job recently in order to optimize the pipeline. A goal of the job is to set some common environment for each instance of the `.build` one:

```yaml
stages:
 - ...
 - prebuild
 - build
 - ...

.prebuild:
  stage: prebuild
  script:
    - prebuild_script
    - ...
  ...

.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - build_script
    - ...
  ...
```

So if a project runs the `build` stage, it must explicitly implement the `prebuild` one too (but only once as it's the common preparation stage for the following build stages):

```yaml
prebuild:
  extends: .prebuild
  ...

build-stage1:
  extends: .build
  ...

build-stage2:
  extends: .build
  ...
```

The question is whether it's possible to attach the `prebuild_script` to the `build_script` so it is proceeded only once no matter how many times the `.build` job is inherited. Or is there a workaround?

I've tried to search some solution in the job rules but there is no option that fits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe gitlab reference can help you.
Take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).